# PostgreSQL timezone does not match system timezone

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I have several PostgreSQL 9.2 installations where the timezone used by PostgreSQL is GMT, despite the entire system being "Europe/Vienna". I double-checked that `postgresql.conf` does *not* contain `timezone` setting, so according to the documentation it should fallback to the system's timezone.

However,

```
# su -s /bin/bash postgres -c "psql mydb"

mydb=# show timezone;
 TimeZone 
----------
 GMT
(1 row)

mydb=# select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2013-11-12 08:14:21.697622+00
(1 row)
```

Any hints, where the GMT timezone could come from? The system user does not have `TZ` set and the `/etc/timezone` and `/etc/timeinfo` seem to be configured correctly.

```
# cat /etc/timezone 
Europe/Vienna
# date
Tue Nov 12 09:15:42 CET 2013
```

Any hints are appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The default value for the `TimeZone` setting has changed on release 9.2:

- [9.1 `TimeZone`:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE)

> (..) If not explicitly set, the server initializes this variable to the
>   time zone specified by its system environment. (...)

- [9.2 `TimeZone`:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE)

> (...) The built-in default is GMT, but that is typically overridden in
>   postgresql.conf; initdb will install a setting there corresponding to
>   its system environment. (...)

Which means that prior to version 9.2 the default value at `postgresql.conf` should be set during `initdb` phase. If you overridden that value (probably copying the old `postgresql.conf` while upgrading from older versions) PostgreSQL will use the "GMT" value as default.

The solution for your case is quite simple, just change the `TimeZone` setting on `postgresql.conf` to the value you want:

```
TimeZone = 'Europe/Vienna'
```

After that you need to `reload` the service:

```
# su - postgres -c "psql mydb -c 'SELECT pg_reload_conf()'"
```

Then all fields stored as `timestamp with time zone` (or `timestamptz`) will be shown correctly from now on. But you will have to correct by hand all (update) the fields stored as `timestamp without time zone` (or `timestamp`).

A tip I give to everyone upgrading PostgreSQL is not to copy the old `postgresql.conf` to the new cluster (notice I'm not sure if it what you did, but I saw this very same problem a lot because of that). Just get the one generated by `initdb` and add the modifications (a `diff` tool may be handful to this task).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not notice this change from 9.1 to 9.2. Yes, adding the timezone info to postgresql.conf is a trivial fix, I just couldn't explain why it would fall back to GMT. Apparently I just stumbled upon the 9.1 documentation all the time, as I wouldn't have expected such a radical change from 9.1 to 9.2 in the default behavior.

Comment: Your database should always be in UTC (GMT) though. Makes times easier to compare. Can always change timezone of client/session. Set timezone x in pg .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices

Comment: Is there any way to specify in `postgresql.conf` for version 9.2+ that the system environment timezone should still be automatically detected?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this.

just create a symlink inside **/usr/share/zoneinfo/** named **localtime** (or whatever name you wish) to be pointing at **/etc/localtime**

```
/usr/share/zoneinfo/localtime -> /etc/localtime
```

this way you're creating a string of links that ultimately points at your system's timezone.

```
/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles
```

Now take the name of the link you created (**localtime** in my case) and use it as the value of the configuration item in postgresql.conf

```
TimeZone = 'localtime'
```

restart postgresql and check the time with "SELECT now();" and "show timezone;"